# POSTing Zip Files to Django REST Framework with de-Serialization

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Using the Django REST Framework, I would like to build a REST endpoint that I can `POST` to with a zip file containing multiple files. I would like the POSTed zip file to then be unzipped and contents then mapped to one or more `Models`. My Models look like:

```
class Package(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class File(models.Model):
    package = models.ForeignKey(Package)
    hash = models.CharField(...)
    filename = models.FileField(upload_to="files")
```

I would like that when I `POST` the zip file, the serializer creates one new `Package` and a `File` for each file contained in the upload zip.

My initial thought would be to subclass a `ModelSerializer` and override the `field_from_native` method to something like:

```
 def field_from_native(self, data, files, field_name, into):
     data['file_set'] = self.make_file_set_from_zip(files[zip_field_name])
```

Is this the right approach to handling a zip file in DRF?

Comment: did you found solution for same, i have similar issue.

Comment: Take a look at `SimpleUploadedFile`.